# Get a JSX's elements class name after load and on change

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit lost learning React here.

I'm trying to get the class name of an element so I can inject an inline color depending on that class name. For example, if the element below has the class 'Active'.

```
<li className="active" >
```

I was experimenting trying to use the onChange event to see if it worked but I can't seem to fetch and print anything in the console. I assumed the event would have triggered after load and when the clase name changes, doesn't seem the case.

```
<li className="active" onChange={(e)=> {(console.log(e.target.className))}}
```

I've read a bit about React refs but it seems too much for such a simple thing. What am I missing here?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be "injecting" colours based on class name, by which I assume you mean do DOM manipulations. There's a few options, though without much context it's hard to say which would be best. One option is to change the class name based on some dynamic value, then define the styling for that class in your CSS, e.g. `className={props.active ? 'active' : ''}` and in your CSS just have `.active { color: #00FF00 }`. Depends on how you are controlling the active-ness of these list elements

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444 In this case I have to inject it inline because it's a dynamic colour that comes directly from the DB since can be changed by the user and thus cannot recompile the CSS after  every change.

Comment: Then probably the most React-y way is to store that DB response in state and use its value to render an inline style prop, e.g. `const [customColor, setCustomColor] = useState()`, load the data from DB into state and then have `<li ... style={{ color: customColor }}/>`. In most cases, values that affect what's rendered should be stored in state (other times refs and such) so we can avoid having to do direct DOM stuff

Comment: @Jayce444 yes, that's somewhat what I'm currently doing. This particular element, however, comes from a plugin. I don't want to touch much that part of the code so that's why I want to inject a colour depending if the className 'Active' is there and listen to any changes in the class to update the colour again

Comment: Hmm it might be better to add more context, the fact that it's a plugin and not your own code was pretty significant haha. Some more contexts and specifics might help

Comment: You are right. I'll unpack things a bit later on. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use onChange event. You probably want to use the document object wherever you want to change the style of an element.

```
        document.getElementsByClassName("Active")[0].style.color = '#fff';
```

You can use it in a function and trigger it wherever you want, or just simply put it inside useEffect hook to execute on component mount.